# What does the phrasal verb "get on" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the movie "Get Out" by Jordan Peele

The person speaking is saying this because there was an incident involving that person during this social gathering and now he informs others that he will retire to another room for rest.

"Well, I'll have to let you all **get on** the rest of the night without the aid of my marvelous  wit"

Two suspects I've in mind:

**get on**

To fare, cope, or manage.
We've been getting on well ever since my husband got a new job.
Let me know how you get on at your new job.

**get on**

6. To make progress with something; continue something: Stop complaining about the work and get on with it. I'll get right on your request!

Does it mean that they will have to continue the rest of the night without the aid of his marvelous  wit **or** to manage(to be entertained for example) for the rest of the night without the aid of his marvelous  wit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the first one. It's like saying, "*I'm sure you'll all survive somehow without me*", where the joke is inflating your importance to the group's ability to continue to have fun without you.